# Que le pasa a mi código?

Tags: python, python-3.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que le pasa a mi programa, alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: La variable `grades` no tiene datos. Agrega un `print` para verificarlo

Comment: Lectura urgente: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21

Answer (score -2):

Tu archivo no se está cargando adecuadamente. Deberías asegurarte de que la función get_grades(file) te devuelve una lista de números.

Comment: No he sido yo quien te ha dado votos negativos, sin embargo creo entender por qué y, como nadie ha dejado comentarios, te lo dejo yo:  El código fuente y mensajes de error son preferidos en texto y [no en capturas de pantalla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21) y, en [answer], encontrarás las razones por las que es mejor responder a preguntas bien formadas.